Conditional CSS to change column widths according to table header value type
I work with a survey engine and when creating surveys, I often have to create grid type questions, which are question types where there are several elements (rows) to evaluate on a scale (columns). The scale can be numerical (ex. 0 through 10), or an all-labelled smaller scale (ex. "Not at all satisfied", "Unsatisfied", "Neutral", "Satisfied", "Very satisfied"). Sometimes, additional columns can be added for options like "Don't know", "Not applicable" or "Prefer not to answer".
The survey engine doesn't prioritize the column widths the way I would like it. It prioritizes the scale columns and reduces the first column that contains the question elements. This is unwanted as when you have question elements with quite a bit of wording, you can end up with just a few words per line (text wrap) and it makes the elements hard to read. Fortunately, the software allows me to add my own CSS and Javascript (applied to the entire survey). I am able to fix the column prioritization quite easily and put fix column widths for the scale columns.
However, the problem is that for questions with a numerical scale, I'd like a certain column width (smaller because there can be 10-13 columns), whereas with labelled scales, another column width (larger because there are fewer columns and the scale labels require more space than numbers). The survey engine creates all the HTML that is output on the respondents' screens, therefore I cannot add attributes such as id's, names, classes, etc. to the HTML tags. I can add HTML wherever I can put text, I have a place in the project settings for additional CSS (I can overwrite existing engine CSS as well), and a place to add Javascript. Seeing as all these are applied survey-wide, I need something to be able to distinguish the two different types of scales so that the column width's are either smaller for numerical scales or larger for labelled scales.
Below is a simplified (but accurate) recreation of the tables the engine creates for grid questions. The "R#" values are simply placeholders for the radio/check buttons.  In in th tags, the engine automatically adds a div around anything I put in the header. In the first table below, I also added by own div's to have the extremes of the numerical scale labelled to overlap other cells. The second table represents a labelled scale grid.
The following is the CSS that I made which works perfectly for numerical scales (tested) but isn't very practical for labelled scales. I could make CSS for labelled scales but wouldn't have the desired outcome for numerical scales.


table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table tr:first-child th {
  vertical-align: bottom !important;
}

th:nth-child(1) {
  width: auto;
}

th:nth-child(n+2) {
  width: 36px;
}

table tr:first-child th:nth-child(2) div div:first-child {
  width: 36px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table tr:first-child th:last-child div div:first-child {
  width: 36px;
  direction: rtl;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table tr:first-child th:nth-last-child(2) div div:first-child {
  width: 36px;
  direction: rtl;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table tr:first-child th:nth-last-child(3) div div:first-child {
  width: 36px;
  direction: rtl;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
  font-weight: normal;
}
<table>
  <colgroup><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col></colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th><div><div>Not at all satisfied</div><div>1</div></div></th>
      <th><div>2</div></th>
      <th><div>3</div></th>
      <th><div>4</div></th>
      <th><div>5</div></th>
      <th><div>6</div></th>
      <th><div>7</div></th>
      <th><div>8</div></th>
      <th><div>9</div></th>
      <th><div><div>Very satisfied</div><div>10</div></div></th>
      <th><div>I don't know</div></th>
      <th><div>I don't want to answer</div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec imperdiet id nisl sed gravida. Sed ipsum tellus</div></th>
      <td>R1</td>
      <td>R2</td>
      <td>R3</td>
      <td>R4</td>
      <td>R5</td>
      <td>R6</td>
      <td>R7</td>
      <td>R8</td>
      <td>R9</td>
      <td>R10</td>
      <td>RD</td>
      <td>RN</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <colgroup><col><col><col><col><col><col><col></colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th><div>Not at all satisfied</div></th>
      <th><div>Unsatisfied</div></th>
      <th><div>Neutral</div></th>
      <th><div>Satisfied</div></th>
      <th><div>Very satisfied</div></th>
      <th><div>I don't know</div></th>
      <th><div>I don't want to answer</div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec imperdiet id nisl sed gravida. Sed ipsum tellus</div></th>
      <td>R1</td>
      <td>R2</td>
      <td>R3</td>
      <td>R4</td>
      <td>R5</td>
      <td>RD</td>
      <td>RN</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



Is there a way to have CSS (or CSS+JS) that would detect if the scale is numerical (or if the scale has 10 or more columns could work as a detection method as well, though detecting numerical values would be more fool proof in my opinion) and apply different column widths?
Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p5n9wzx4/2/

:has makes styling based on a minimum number of columns easy. For tables with at least ten columns use table:has(col:nth-of-type(10)) ...

Thanks @Alohci! This solution works just as I hoped.

Now my next question: How do I make your comment the accepted answer? lol
